# Deadlock due to serializable isolation level(from my knowledge)

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, isolation-level

Deadlock occurring on update. Both the updates holding RangeS-S lock and waiting for X lock. Is there any other possible way without changing the isolation level or using the retry logic?

```
Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
<deadlock-list><deadlock victim="Victim">
 &#x20;<process-list>
  &#x20;<process id="Victim" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 7:72058476792053760 (ad54c97e3b66)" waittime="507" ownerId="11291846386" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-08-16T17:14:03.530" XDES="0x1e2bbdeee80" lockMode="X" schedulerid="10" kpid="22204" status="suspended" spid="185" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-08-16T17:14:03.547" lastbatchcompleted="2021-08-16T17:14:03.497" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.497" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="VM-ASE-WEB-1" hostpid="6988" loginname="mypadmin" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="11291846386" currentdb="7" currentdbname="MYP" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   &#x20;<executionStack>
    &#x20;<frame procname="DB.dbo.Count1" line="136" stmtstart="13838" stmtend="15002" sqlhandle="0x030007000926c357da4d7b0100ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE TableA SET
        AdminFundsWip = 0, AdminFundsRed = 0, AdminFundsAwaitingSignedDocs = 0, AdminFundsCompleted = 0,
        AuditFundsWip = 0, AuditFundsRed = 0, AuditFundsAwaitingSignedDocs = 0, AuditFundsCompleted = 0,
        AdminAuditFundsWip = 0, AdminAuditFundsRed = 0, AdminAuditFundsAwaitingSignedDocs = 0, AdminAuditFundsCompleted = 0
        -- Only update the current month count or the end-of-(financial)-year numbers (not previous non-end months!)
        WHERE ([Month] = @ActiveMonth OR MONTH([Month]) = 6) AND ClientBusinessGuid = @SelectedClien     </frame>
    &#x20;<frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="88" sqlhandle="0x0100070098c1ac002053d2a0e401000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SAA_CountFunds @p0, @p1     </frame>
    &#x20;<frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
   &#x20;</executionStack>
   &#x20;<inputbuf>
(@p0 datetimeoffset(7),@p1 uniqueidentifier)SAA_CountFunds @p0, @p1    </inputbuf>
  &#x20;</process>
  &#x20;<process id="process1df3917d088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 7:72058476792053760 (4a9e26a214ab)" waittime="1096" ownerId="11291849441" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-08-16T17:14:04.243" XDES="0x1e0a6673650" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="13864" status="suspended" spid="209" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-08-16T17:14:04.260" lastbatchcompleted="2021-08-16T17:14:04.200" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.200" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="VM-ASE-WEB-1" hostpid="6988" loginname="mypadmin" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="11291849441" currentdb="7" currentdbname="MYP" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   &#x20;<executionStack>
    &#x20;<frame procname="DB.dbo.Count1" line="136" stmtstart="13838" stmtend="15002" sqlhandle="0x030007000926c357da4d7b0100ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE TableA SET
        AdminFundsWip = 0, AdminFundsRed = 0, AdminFundsAwaitingSignedDocs = 0, AdminFundsCompleted = 0,
        AuditFundsWip = 0, AuditFundsRed = 0, AuditFundsAwaitingSignedDocs = 0, AuditFundsCompleted = 0,
        AdminAuditFundsWip = 0, AdminAuditFundsRed = 0, AdminAuditFundsAwaitingSignedDocs = 0, AdminAuditFundsCompleted = 0
        -- Only update the current month count or the end-of-(financial)-year numbers (not previous non-end months!)
        WHERE ([Month] = @ActiveMonth OR MONTH([Month]) = 6) AND ClientBusinessGuid = @SelectedClien     </frame>
    &#x20;<frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="88" sqlhandle="0x0100070098c1ac002053d2a0e401000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SAA_CountFunds @p0, @p1     </frame>
    &#x20;<frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
   &#x20;</executionStack>
   &#x20;<inputbuf>
(@p0 datetimeoffset(7),@p1 uniqueidentifier)SAA_CountFunds @p0, @p1    </inputbuf>
  &#x20;</process>
 &#x20;</process-list>
 &#x20;<resource-list>
  &#x20;<keylock hobtid="72058476792053760" dbid="7" objectname="DB.dbo.Count1" indexname="PK_Count1" id="lock1e2e10f9a80" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72058476792053760">
   &#x20;<owner-list>
    &#x20;<owner id="process1df3917d088" mode="RangeS-S"/>
   &#x20;</owner-list>
   &#x20;<waiter-list>
    &#x20;<waiter id="Victim" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
   &#x20;</waiter-list>
  &#x20;</keylock>
  &#x20;<keylock hobtid="72058476792053760" dbid="7" objectname="DB.dbo.Count1" indexname="PK_Count1" id="lock1df701ca900" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72058476792053760">
   &#x20;<owner-list>
    &#x20;<owner id="Victim" mode="RangeS-S"/>
   &#x20;</owner-list>
   &#x20;<waiter-list>
    &#x20;<waiter id="process1df3917d088" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
   &#x20;</waiter-list>
  &#x20;</keylock>
 &#x20;</resource-list>
&#x20;</deadlock></deadlock-list>
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the full query and the index definitions, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. If this is being run inside an explicit transaction, please add the same for all other statements in the transaction

Comment: Not that this will solve your problem per se, but for what it's worth, you generally should use TempTables instead of Table Variables, in almost all cases. There are a lot of negative performance drawbacks to using Table Variables. In this particular case, I'm referring to your `@ActiveMonths` Table Variable.

Comment: Looks like you need to get rid of that Distinct Sort and get the index seek on `SAA_CountFunds` to be always be in order of key (a merge join). Without seeing your indexes can't say for sure. `WHERE ([Month] = @ActiveMonth OR MONTH([Month]) = 6)` doesn't make any sense: if `Month` is an integer why are you using `MONTH()` function on it, if it is a date why are you comparing it to `6`? And you should not use functions on `WHERE` or `JOIN` predicates because this prevents using indexes properly. There are quite a number of other inefficiencies in the batch also.